# Plugins for Java Spring application

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Suppose I have a Java `Spring`-based client application, which sends a request to a server and process the response. It uses `Command` pattern for the response processing.

Now I would like to discover and load these `Commands` in run-time. How would you implement it?

I am aware of "plugin" technologies, such as `JPF` and `OSGI` but they look as a huge overkill for me. I am thinking about using `Spring's` autowiring. Would you recommend it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking for a very nice, light and very functional plugin framework, have a look at [Java Simple Plugin Framework](http://code.google.com/p/jspf/). I have made extensive use of this and it works great.

Using Spring's *autowiring*, you have to consider the implications around it. eg. you can only autowire Spring Beans etc etc.

Comment: Needs article on integration with Spring or the library should include wrappers for Spring.

Answer (score 7):

The [spring-plugin](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-plugin) project is probably worth looking at for this need. Unlike JSPF in the accepted answer, spring-plugin is designed specifically for Spring. It touts itself as "The smallest plugin system ever" which might be debatable (I replaced my own mini-framework that was even smaller/lighter) but it's definitely easy to swallow and yet flexible.